# Django OAuth Toolkit setup issue

Tags: django, oauth, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I am following https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.0/rest-framework/getting_started.html for setting up Django OAuth Toolkit with rest framework.

As on step 4: https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.0/rest-framework/getting_started.html#step-4-get-your-token-and-use-your-api

It says to get token, we need to do a curl like:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" http://<client_id>:<client_secret>@localhost:8000/o/token/
```

My Actual curl request for this process looks something like this(for already generated client_id and client_secret)

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=test&password=test" http://mbqvonqO7sI1lrh87uDd.C1U..NbKTb@0=eCM8Fl::2O=!0ZjE5UCha0UW?Oie-XCVUn;3XtmjT2SbFpzDJeM@Bn3.vPS!KLoDqVz7L-3.FfjP9v6yYyu2ghxObnIdIWppu=J@RPxPOfU@Q7KPt7da.?Bg0o5kCt5tY:wamsF@127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/
```

which didn't return any response and gives an error "bash: !0: event not found"

Any wrong in call made?

Comment: Try to enclose within double or single quotes your url, because it contains a lot of letters not eligible for shell args without quotes.

Comment: I noticed that you also have an at sign and columns in your client_id and client_secret. I think that curl parser cannot distinguish client and client_secret there.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with the "client id" and "client secret" generated during register application(http://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.0/rest-framework/getting_started.html#step-3-register-an-application)

"client id" and "client secret" contains special characters which can't be used with curl request in the mentioned way in documentation.

We can use it with the way suggested by Almalki as:

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=password&username=YOUR_USERNAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set client_id and client_secret as POST parameters:

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=password&username=YOUR_USERNAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP and this was the only solution that worked for me:

```
curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>' --user '<client_id>:<client_secret>' 'http://localhost:8000/o/token/'
```

I found this solution at [Django OAuth Toolkit's Github issue #167](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit/issues/167).  There is a great explanation there.